# What's all the valid file name for scons?

Tags: config, filenames, scons

I tried SConstruct, Sconstruct, sconstruct, all seems to be OK.

My question:
1. Is it case insensitive that all 'sconstruct' files? I think linux system file name is case sensitive, is it by python that scons is case insensitive regarding with file names?

2. If there's 'sconstruct' file, scons prints:

   $ scons
   scons: Reading SConscript files ...
   scons: done reading SConscript files.
   scons: Building targets ...
   scons: `.' is up to date.
   scons: done building targets.

Why it says "Reading SConscript file", not saying "Reading SConstruct file"?

I guess it's in old versions of scons, make file names are "SConscript", right? But I tried to rename "SConstruct" to "SConscript", then it prints out:

```
$ scons

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
```

This is so weird to me, what is a "SConscript" concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about the file name casing of SConstruct see the man page: http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

> By default, scons searches for a file named SConstruct, Sconstruct, or
>   sconstruct (in that order) in the current directory and reads its
>   configuration from the first file found. An alternate file name may be
>   specified via the -f option.

For a better understanding of SCons.. reading the users guide is also recommended.  In the case of your question about what is SConscript?

http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch14.html

> 14.1. SConscript Files
>
> As we've already seen, the build script at the top of the tree is
>   called SConstruct. The top-level SConstruct file can use the
>   SConscript function to include other subsidiary scripts in the build.
>   These subsidiary scripts can, in turn, use the SConscript function to
>   include still other scripts in the build. By convention, these
>   subsidiary scripts are usually named SConscript. For example, a
>   top-level SConstruct file might arrange for four subsidiary scripts to
>   be included in the build as follows: